# Trouble running $wpdb->query() with last_insert_id

Tags: database, mysql, wpdb

I am trying to get a primary key from a coupon table to put it in my target table as a foreign key. In between I would like to run a query to get the last insert id. I can't get the syntax right though

```
$couponId = $wpdb->query("select last_insert_id() from frequentVisitorCoupons_coupons");
  var_dump($couponId); // false
$couponId = $wpdb->query("select * from frequentVisitorCoupons_coupons where last_insert_id()");
  var_dump($couponId); // false
```

What is the correct syntax for this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the last inserted ID from `$wpdb` with the `insert_id` property:

```
$wpdb->insert( ... );
$couponId = $wpdb->insert_id
```